# Summarize results of Pandas compare() function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare

I am trying to compare two dataframes and the picture below is showing the results of Pandas compare() function. Now I am trying to summarize the result and I want to count all the values that did not match, i.e NaN = correct. I know how to access the columns but not the "sub-columns" *self / other*.

[image: Pandas dataframe]

Comment: Do you mind showing sample of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
data = {('Ask_Avg_Volume', 'self'): [0.0, nan, 0.0],
        ('Ask_Avg_Volume', 'other'): [1.0, nan, 1.0],
        ('Avg_Order_Insert_Size', 'self'): [nan, nan, nan],
        ('Avg_Order_Insert_Size', 'other'): [nan, nan, nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
  Ask_Avg_Volume       Avg_Order_Insert_Size      
            self other                  self other
0            0.0   1.0                   NaN   NaN
1            NaN   NaN                   NaN   NaN
2            0.0   1.0                   NaN   NaN
```

IIUC, you want to select `other` columns using index slicing and count `NaN` values per variable (first level index of columns):

```
>>> df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'other')].droplevel(1, axis=1).isna().sum()

Ask_Avg_Volume           1
Avg_Order_Insert_Size    3
dtype: int64
```